# Implementing a pipe-like program without wait?

Tags: c, linux

So I implemented a program that takes an input file, two command strings and an output file to mimick the behaviour of running :

`<input cmd1 -option | cmd2 -option > output`

that's called like this :

`./pipe input "cmd1 -opt"  "cmd2 -opt" output`

and I did without using the `wait` system call since while there are open file descriptors on the pipe I opened, the exec'd commands will wait for one another. that is the pipe takes care of coordination IIUC.

But I feel like I am doing it wrong since it seems that people I using `wait()` out of convention. Is it reasonnable to think it is not necessary in my case since I only need the return value of the second command and the pipe ensures communication or am I missing something ? What else am I doing wrong in terms of code structure or style ?

Here is my code :

````c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "pipex.h"

static const char   g_cmd_not_found[] = {
    "command not found: "
};

static const char   g_empty_string[] = {
    "The name of the input or output file cannot be an empty string\n"
};

static int  open_or_die(char *filename, int flags, mode_t mode)
{
    int fd;

    fd = open(filename, flags, mode);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        if (*filename == '\0')
            write(STDERR_FILENO, g_empty_string, sizeof(g_empty_string));
        else
        {
            write(STDERR_FILENO, "pipex: ", sizeof("pipex: "));
            perror(filename);
        }
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    return (fd);
}

static void pipe_or_die(int *pipe_fds)
{
    int r;

    r = pipe(pipe_fds);
    if (r == -1)
    {
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "pipex: ", sizeof("pipex: "));
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

static void file_is_ok_or_die(char **cmdv, char **pathvar_entries)
{
    if (access(cmdv[0], X_OK) == -1)
    {
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "pipex: ", sizeof("pipex: "));
        if (cmdv[0][0] != '/')
        {
            write(STDERR_FILENO, g_cmd_not_found, sizeof(g_cmd_not_found));
            ft_puts_stderr(cmdv[0]);
        }
        else
            perror(cmdv[0]);
        free_null_terminated_array_of_arrays(cmdv);
        free_null_terminated_array_of_arrays(pathvar_entries);
        if (errno == ENOENT)
            exit(127);
        else if (errno == EACCES)
            exit(126);
        else
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

void    execute_pipeline(char *cmd_str, int read_from, int write_to, char **env)
{
    char    **pathvar_entries;
    char    **cmdv;

    redirect_fd_to_fd(0, read_from);
    redirect_fd_to_fd(1, write_to);
    pathvar_entries = ft_split(get_path_var(env), ':');
    cmdv = ft_split(cmd_str, ' ');
    if (!pathvar_entries || !cmdv)
    {
        write(STDERR_FILENO, "pipex: ", sizeof("pipex: "));
        perror("malloc");
        free_null_terminated_array_of_arrays(cmdv);
        free_null_terminated_array_of_arrays(pathvar_entries);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    cmdv[0] = get_command_path(cmdv, get_pwd_var(env), pathvar_entries);
    file_is_ok_or_die(cmdv, pathvar_entries);
    execve(cmdv[0], cmdv, env);
    free_null_terminated_array_of_arrays(cmdv);
    free_null_terminated_array_of_arrays(pathvar_entries);
}

int main(int ac, char **av, char **envp)
{
    int     pipefd[2];
    int     child_pid;
    int     infile_fd;
    int     outfile_fd;

    if (ac != 5)
        print_usage_exit();
    pipe_or_die(pipefd);
    child_pid = fork();
    if (child_pid == -1)
        perror("fork");
    else if (child_pid == 0)
    {
        infile_fd = open_or_die(av[1], O_RDONLY, 0000);
        close(pipefd[0]);
        execute_pipeline(av[2], infile_fd, pipefd[1], envp);
    }
    else
    {
        outfile_fd = open_or_die(av[ac - 1], O_WRONLY | O_CREAT | O_TRUNC, 0666);
        close(pipefd[1]);
        execute_pipeline(av[3], pipefd[0], outfile_fd, envp);
    }
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```
````

Comment: What's `"pipex.h"`?  It seems to be essential for this program, but I don't know what I need to install to compile this.

Comment: @TobySpeight It's just a global header. I haven't put all the functions I am using because it would be too big and some of them are not relevant to what mattered fr me to show you

Comment: You might like to post it for its own review - I'm wondering what's in `redirect_fd_to_fd()` that plain old `dup2()` doesn't do, for instance.  And I'd like to know whether `ft_split()` is any better than passing the command string to `sh -c`, for a much simpler `exec()` setup.

Comment: @TobySpeight Thanks for the tip. This is an exercise and I am only allowed to use `execve`. Program usage is like `./pipex infile "cmd1 -op1 -op2" "cm2 -op1 -op2" outfile` which is why I have to use a split, to split the command string. `redirect_fd_to_fd` doesn't to much than `dup2` but for calling `close` before dup2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Error handling

The way you handle error is quite unusual. Why use `write()` instead of `fprintf(stderr, ...)`? Why have some error messages stored in a variable like `g_empty_string`, but other errors messages are passes as literals, like `"pipex: "`? Why try to `open()` first and only if it fails check if `filename` is empty?

On Linux, I recommend you use [`err()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/err) to report errors and exit with an error code in one go. For example:

```
static int open_or_die(const char *filename, int flags, mode_t mode)
{
    if (!filename[0])
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Empty filename");

    int fd = open(filename, flags, mode);

    if (fd == -1)
        err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Error trying to open '%s'", filename);

    return fd;
}
```

## Don't use `access()` to check if you can `execve()`

Instead of first checking with `access()` if a file is executable before calling `execve()`, just call `execve()` unconditionally, and then just check the return value of `execve()`. Otherwise, you will have a [TOCTTOU bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time-of-check_to_time-of-use).

```
if (execve(cmdv[0], cmdv, env) == -1)
    err(EXIT_FAILURE, "Could not execute '%s'", cmdv[0]);
```

Note that if `execve()` succeeds, it will never return, so there's no need to free anything afterwards.

## Why you should `wait()`

If you don't call `wait()`, your program will terminate when the second command terminates. However, consider that the first command might still be doing something. It will then continue in the background, but you won't have control over it anymore. Suppose you want to call `./pipe` twice, and the second call depends on results from the first call, then you would really want to ensure both processes of the first call have finished.

Comment: I would perhaps suggest that the OP use `pthreads` or `openMP` to create threads and join them instead of waiting and hoping that the work is done?

Comment: @upkajdt Unfortunately `execve()` replaces the whole process, not just one thread. Also see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40296502/calling-execv-after-creating-a-thread).

Comment: @G.Sliepen You say "It will then continue in the background, but you won't have control over it anymore."         Indeed                                                                            

I can see that `./pipex /dev/stdin cat  ls outfile` does not wait for input indeed but I am not sure why it is the case. Why can't the zombie `cat` read from stdin even though the main process is over ? It should still run right ?

Comment: @cassepipe `cat` will still run but then the question is: what happens with `/dev/stdin` after `ls` exits? If I try to run that command in a shell, then after it finishes, the `cat` process is still running, but as soon as I press any key it exits with the error: `cat: -: Input/output error`.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Not sure I understand but to answer your question I have no idea as to what happens to `/dev/stdin` after `ls` exits. I'd say nothing since I `open`ed the input file in the child process. When I run `</dev/stdin cat | ls` in a terminal it prints the ls output and then waits for input. I can enter one line, press `Return` and then I get back to the shell prompt, no error message.

Comment: @cassepipe Yes but the shell properly `wait()`s for the `cat` process to finish. What happens then is that `cat` reads the line from `stdin`, tries to write it to `stdout`, and then gets an `EPIPE` error because the `ls` process already terminated.

Comment: @G.Sliepen Sorry to insist so much and thanks for your time but I want to get it. I understand the shell behaviour but what I don't understand is my program's behaviour and why it is not the same, Even though the parent returns with `ls`, the child, shouldn't the child be able to coninue its life that is, ask for input and then get its `EPIPE` just as the shell does without a `wait` ?

Comment: @cassepipe No, in your shell example, the shell waits for `cat` to finish and keeps its `stdin` redirected to the `cat` process. In your case, your program terminates early and then the shell that started your program wants its `stdin` back. I'm not sure though why it doesn't immediately get an `EPIPE` from `stdin`, but only when you try to type something in the shell.

Comment: @G.Sliepen  You say that "the shell wants its `stdin` back" but I quite don't understand that. The shell must have a file descriptor to `stdin` just as my orphan process does. There's nothing preventing my orphan `cat` to read from stdin as well the shell is there ?
From what you've told me my guess is the following : When my program terminates, the shell prints the prompt to stdout and then both the orphan cat and the shell are reading from stdin. So cat also reads from stdin, gets an EPIPE and quietly becomes a zombie without anybody noticing. Does that make sense ?